# Sqlite view across multiple databases

Tags: view, sqlite

Is it possible to create a VIEW (not temporary view) in a Sqlite database that has other databases attached to it?
The view should be able to access data from all databases via joined tables.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, the view must be temporary, otherwise an error will occur:

```
sqlite> create view view1 as select * from db2.foo union select * from main.foo;
Error: view view1 cannot reference objects in database db2
sqlite> create temp view view1 as select * from db2.foo union select * from main.foo;
sqlite> select * from view1;
...
```

This makes sense since a temporary view is part of the automatically created `temp` database which only exists for the current process.

**EDIT:**

You can list the temporary tables and views (all stored in the automatically created `temp` database) this way:

```
sqlite> .headers on
sqlite> select * from sqlite_temp_master;
type|name|tbl_name|rootpage|sql
view|view1|view1|0|CREATE VIEW view1 as select * from db2.foo union select * from main.foo
```

To list views only:

```
select * from sqlite_temp_master where type='view';
```

Comment: Is it possible to get a list of these views, then?

Comment: Fantastic. Makes a ton of sense and thanks for explaining it as well.

Comment: Related feature request for Navicat: https://community.navicat.com/forum/navicat-sales-and-feedback/feedback/5144-possibility-to-save-views-that-reference-attached-databases